# python string replace only special characters keeping non-english alphabets

Tags: regex, pandas, string, dataframe, python-3.8

How can I remove only special characters from a string, but not foreign language characters. When I try the below code, it removes both special characters and non-english alphabets.  But I want to remove only special characters (special characters that appear in regular English sentences).

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
id,name
1,A
1,B
1,C
1,D
2,E
2,F
2,ds
2,G
2, dsds
3,Endüstrisi`
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

df['name'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z\d\s]','',regex=True)
```

The above code results in

```
0            A
1            B
2            C
3            D
4            E
5            F
6           ds
7            G
8         dsds
9    Endstrisi
Name: name, dtype: object
```

But what I want is

The above code results in

```
0            A
1            B
2            C
3            D
4            E
5            F
6           ds
7            G
8         dsds
9    Endüstrisi
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Your expected output seems to be identical to the one you get. But you just need `df['name'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]|_','',regex=True)`

Comment: I was with the impression that `\w` matches only english letters and numbers.

Comment: No, in Python 3, the regex shorthand character classes are Unicode aware by default,  the `re.U` flag is on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]|_', '', regex=True)
```

In Python 3, all regex shorthand character classes (like `\w`, `\d`, `\s`) are Unicode aware by default, as the `re.U` (`re.UNICODE`) flag is on by default. Thus, if you use `\w` construct in a negated character class, it matches all chars other than any Unicode letters, digits and `_`.

Since you do not want to match whitespaces, `\s` is added to the negated character class.

An underscore cannot be included into the negated character class (since it will not be matched then), you need an alternative to match `_`.

So, the pattern matches

- `[^\w\s]` - any char but Unicode letters, digits, whitespaces and `_`
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore.

Comment: Excellent, just what I've been looking for. Tested this quite a bit, seems to be working fine. Thanks!